# Prevent action on child div mouseover

Tags: jquery

I've got one div inside another and js to fire on mouseover and mouseout on employeejob. The problem is that when I hover over the little box div, the mouseout event fires and then the mouseover event fires. How can I prevent this from happening on hover of the 'littlebox' div?

```
<div class="employeejob>
          <i class="littlebox">                                                        
          </i>
</div>


//function 1
$('.employeejob').on('mouseover', function() {
  
   //some js

});   


//function 2
$('.employeejob').on('mouseout', function() {

    //some js

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mouseenter and mouseleave :)